# Calculate Euclidean distance on a torus

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Euclidean distance between two lattice points \$(x_1,  y_1)\$ and \$(x_2,  y_2)\$ on a plane is: \$\sqrt{(x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2}\$.

Imagine now a lattice `N x N` replicated infinitely many times next to itself. The two points \$(x_1, y_1)\$ and \$(x_2, y_2)\$ also get replicated. Euclidean distance on a torus is then the minimal distance between all these points.

Input: `x1, y1, x2, y2` and `N`. Arrange these in any convenient order or way (e.g. represent \$(3,4)\$, \$(5,6)\$ as 4 arguments `3, 4, 5, 6`, two complex numbers \$3+4j\$, \$5+6j\$, a list `[[3,4],[5,6]]`, a list `[3,4,5,6]` or anything that's not too bizarre). Coordinates must be integers in the range `0..N-1` or `1..N`. The size of the torus (`N`) must be an integer (you can assume `1 < N < 100`).

Output: a real number, with precision better than \$1\%\$.

Test cases:

| x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | N | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0.00 |
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 2.83 |
| 0 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 2.24 |
| 9 | 0 | 9 | 8 | 10 | 2.00 |
| 12 | 34 | 56 | 78 | 99 | 62.23 |
| 0 | 0 | 98 | 98 | 99 | 1.41 |

Answer (score 10):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 40 bytes

```r
\(a,b,N)sum(pmin((d=a-b)%%N,-d%%N)^2)^.5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bdBLCsIwEIBh3HqKghQSmJYkfZgscoWcQCqpQShYK32cxk1duPU-ehrbhkqL2SSz-Pgz5P6o-1db1VVh9OVoiqaVz649B_yNDkhDDgo3XYluZXFFyEgd5Nj3FQRmOHHGcBYm1n82ySqDtDwhCgRDPg0Ug5IMezuPbv8hg8jCaVAyHiFxQDIXGbAfZCGPnFasXqfEYhY7sJjDAvgCOyQddoytTVLYT1qIUadD273I3OYgFp6GMbW_1_f2_gI)

Input the two points as vectors `a` and `b`.

Comment: `\(a,b,N)sum(((a-b+N/2)%%N-N/2)^2)^.5` (36 bytes) is a small improvement on this idea based on finding the distance from (a - b + N/2) to (N/2, N/2)

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn - that's more than just an improvement, I think, and a good byte-save, too.  Please post it yourself and take all the credit!  Well done!

Answer (score 7):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @ngn.

Function taking input as `f[N;(x1,y1;x2,y2)]`.

```
{%+/&/x*x!:y-|y}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxFjcEOgjAQRM/0K9ZGBTSWtiDS9h84eAUSLsLFeBGTNui/u60Qk+1k83ZmOuh5d8z2mT3YjXant/sQMuq5scI4Yaw0TpraXG/P133qCAxNbSBJwjU1SbinaYehSVMBEYdIhJGojHMCALjmAaAWaFkwD24ZBrFkVb5gtZYIb2Cy8FwFO2q18l+N8MWYP5cQXfCm0FJiKP//oarl+WJWCEp6rrcji1kc03aiLeoDly82wDIm)

`y-|y` Subtract the reversed list of points from the list of points. This results in component-wise distances in both directions.
`x!:` Take all values mod *N*. Updates x.
`x*` Square each value.
`&/` take the element-wise minimum between positive and negative difference.
`%+/` Sum, then take the square root.

Comment: shorter if you take `((x1;y1);(x2;y2))` as a single argument: `{%+/&/x*x!:y-|y}`

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ạ/«ạ¥ÆḊ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the coordinates as a pair of pairs* of integers** on the left and the size as an integer** on the right and yields the Euclidean toroidal distance.

* I guess this will work in any integer number of dimensions too.

** Will work with floats too (up to floating point inaccuracies, of course).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroX6h1YDyUNLD7c93NH1////aAMdy1idaEMdw9j/hgYA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hroX6h1YDyUNLD7c93NH1//By/UdNa/7/jwYCBUMdBQWDWB0FCMswFshUMIrV4VIASRoBOcZgSQgLJGkCkzSA6zQC68GQtEQ11tAAJmkJ1wliWaBIGgINMzYBSZqa6SiYgyUtLTHstLQACiMkYwE).

#### How?

\$\text{Distance} = \sqrt{\left (|x_1-x_2| \land ||x_1-x_2|-N| \right )^2 + \left (|y_1-y_2| \land ||y_1-y_2|-N| \right )^2}\$

```
ạ/«ạ¥ÆḊ - Link: Coordinates=[[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]; Size=N
 /      - reduce (Coordinates) by:
ạ       -   ([x1, y1]) absolute difference ([x2, y2])
              -> D = [|x1-x2|, |y1-y2|]
    ¥   - last two links as a dyad - f(D, N):
   ạ    -   (D) absolute difference (N) (vectorises)
              -> D2 = [||x1-x2|-N|, ||y1-y2|-N|]
  «     -   (D) minimum (D2) (vectorises)
              -> M = [min(|x1-x2|, ||x1-x2|-N|), min(|y1-y2|, ||y1-y2|-N|)]
     ÆḊ - norm = vector_length = square_root(sum(squared_values)))
            -> (min(|x1-x2|, ||x1-x2|-N|)^2 + min(|y1-y2|, ||y1-y2|-N|)^2)^(1/2)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [julia](https://julialang.org/), 43 bytes

Notice that for any point \$x\$, the \$N\$-toroidal distance from \$x\$ to \$(N/2, N/2)\$ is the Euclidean distance from \$\mathrm{mod}(x, N)\$ to \$(N/2, N/2)\$.

Hence, we can find the \$N\$-toroidal distance between \$a\$ and \$b\$ by computing the Euclidean distance from \$\mathrm{mod}(a-b+(N/2, N/2), N)\$ to \$(N/2, N/2)\$.

```
d(a,b,N)=sum(@. (mod1(a-b+N/2,N)-N/2)^2)^.5
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XdDRCoIwFAZggq56ikE3E-famdO2i6An8AWiwJDAUIvSp-nGGx-qnqYzXTGEwQ_j23_GeQ3Xrirzvh-69hLpd1jQnJ1ZFuyeXU33nND6VgDNo3OYbSTeRxjBCQ9PpiefxfL-KJu2amhBD8CIODJiEzBlEJA1gZUnJCOxFS7VKIQvhOtAIf9Cch3PkPEGgXBKKl8ZV4WpPeUTsB9RFiUpI1vLjBlZim3zmVObRuNB4AqmZfz2-AU)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>38</s> 33 bytes

```
nNorm[Min[#,n-#]&/@Abs[#-#2]]&
```

Thanks to @att!
Where `` stands for `\[Function]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P@/9pIV@@UW50b6ZedHKOnm6yrFq@g6OScXRyrrKRrGxav8DijLzShzSog0NYqOrDXQsa3UUqg11DGtjuWAylpZgGQOQjKWFjqVFbex/AA)

Input: `[N][{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}]`

Comment: [33](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P@/9pIV@@UW50b6ZedHKOnm6yrFq@g6OScXRyrrKRrGxav8DijLzShzSog0NYqOrDXQsa3UUqg11DGtjuWAylpZgGQOQjKWFjqVFbex/AA) inputting `[N][{x1,y1}, {x2,y2}]`

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
αDŠ-ø€ßnOt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3EaXowt0D@941LTm8Pw8/5L//6MNjXSMTWK5ok3NdMwtYrksLQE)

-1 thanks to *@KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
αDŠ-ø€ßnOt  # Implicit input
α           # Absolute difference between the first two inputs
 D          # Duplicate this pair
  Š         # Triple swap so the input is second
   -        # Subtract the absolute difference between the
            # first two inputs from the third input
    ø       # Zip this with the absolute difference
     €ß     # Minimum of each inner pair
       n    # Square each
        O   # Sum the list
         t  # Square root the sum
            # Implicit output
```

Comment: `D³s-` can be `DŠ-` or `©-®` for -1 byte.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, updated. Btw, is there a command for `nOt` (Jelly and Vyxal have it, but I don't see one in 05AB1E).

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've used `nOt` multiple times in other challenges before, so a 2-byte builtin for it would have been nice to have indeed..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Don't you mean "Unfortunately nOt"?

Comment: @Neil Haha, I guess so indeed. :D

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES7), 64 bytes

Expects `(x1,y1,x2,y2,N)`.

```javascript
(x,y,X,Y,n)=>((g=d=>(d*=d)<(q=n-d**.5)*q?d:q*q)(X-x)+g(Y-y))**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ddBBDoIwEAXQvafoslNbaAsqNVavAUtCgWgMiBgDp8cSajSIi5@/mJfppJf0mbbZ/Xx7sKo2@VDoAXe0pzFNaAX6iHGpjS1DtIEDbnTFDCHeBkhzMvuGNIBj1sG6xAnrAcbRkNVVW19z71qXuMBIUIS4jXCRAMj3kfA4X82otONgJK7DifIFyt1W6eKo9KJgiarPAYK/qQznVLmtY0ff9OcAYR8NQoo2W4p2lio10a1dG/w5VkUu6v0FoRhe)

#### Commented

```javascript
( x, y,       // (x, y) = coordinates of the 1st point
  X, Y,       // (X, Y) = coordinates of the 2nd point
  n           // n = size of the torus
) => (        //
  ( g = d =>  // g is a helper function taking d
    (d *= d)  // square d
    <         // and compare it with
    ( q =     // q defined as:
      n -     //   the difference between n and
      d ** .5 //   the square root of d (which is the
              //   absolute value of the original d)
    ) * q     // multiplied by itself
    ?         // if d is less than q²:
      d       //   return d
    :         // else:
      q * q   //   return q²
  )(X - x) +  // 1st call to g with d = X - x
  g(Y - y)    // 2nd call to g with d = Y - y
) ** .5       // square root of the sum
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 52 bytes

```
[ v- 2dup n-v rot '[ [ _ rem ] map ] bi@ vmin norm ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bdA9b8IwEAbgPb/i3TqBkkABtwsb6tKl6hQhlKYXNSqxzdmJFKH89vRigooE/jrpHp9PcpkX3vDw@fH2vntBnfufeUtjyuGXWNMRJXchD0enhnRBDrlzpnCwTN53livt8RpF5wgyzkhlJ4jRh5hI7CdZBl0EucRbiaeaVOa/JHEg9eC5QGqqUtjckFKjS49lwOcV1nd87ac24xqxHzK0M6TfjYWetWDj8ZQhwwFMNfbyD1bOr2qLtq40tGHJSlFZsfMLIfkSaxyFi/PhDw)

Takes input as `N { x1 y1 } { x2 y2 }`.

```
                   ! 10 { 9 0 } { 9 8 }
v-                 ! 10 { 0 -8 }
2dup               ! 10 { 0 -8 } 10 { 0 -8 }
n-v                ! 10 { 0 -8 } { 10 18 }
rot                ! { 0 -8 } { 10 18 } 10
'[ [ _ rem ] map ] ! { 0 -8 } { 10 18 } [ [ 10 rem ] map ]
bi@                ! { 0 2 } { 0 8 }   (apply quot to both points)
vmin               ! { 0 2 }
norm               ! 2.0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>63</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to [@Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) and -2 thanks to [@xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).*

```python
lambda x,y,X,Y,N:abs((x-X+(k:=N/2))%N-k+((y-Y+k)%N-k)*1j)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3LXMSc5NSEhUqdCp1InQidfysEpOKNTQqdCO0NbKtbP30jTQ1Vf10s7U1NCp1I7WzwRxNLcMsTagBUwuKMvNKNNI0DHUMdAyBEKiBCyZmpGOsA8ImSGIGQHVGQIgqZgnWa2iAJGipAxK2QBU0BBpnomNqpmNuoWNpiWaspQUYAYUhjluwAEIDAA)

Port of [Damian Pavlyshyn's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260743/calculate-euclidean-distance-on-a-torus#comment573669_260757).

Comment: Bah, I was toying with that approach for my Charcoal answer but it turned out to be longer; I didn't think to try other languages.

Comment: `abs(((x-X+(k:=N/2))%N-k)+((y-Y+k)%N-k)*1j)` saves 4 bytes.

Comment: You can remove one of the paren pairs: [TIO](https://tio.run/##XczBCsIwDAbgu0/hRUhdim03tR3sFXrewEuHDLU6y9xhffraFYRN/uSQjyTOj7d3n0s3hK66hKd5tVezndBjjQ3q0rQfgInWGdiy0gdByE5TmwF42mQ2DWTPHyS44d6P0AFHhjwmbm5@JjDHuYuFsbgnYtam0i1nC1Q4s1wjj@8KPJ7wLFGpv7dKpoocvg "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online")

Comment: Indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>60</s> 56 bytes

```ruby
->a,b,n{(-4..4).map{|c|(a-b-n*(c%3-1+1i*c/=3)).abs}.min}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5RJ0knr1pD10RPz0RTLzexoLomuUYjUTdJN09LI1nVWNdQ2zBTK1nf1lhTUy8xqbhWLzczr/Z/gUJatKEOSE7HKJYLxDPSNgayQYQJRMAAyDOC8ywzIaoNDaB8HUttCwTXEKjTJFPH1EzbHChqaQkzwtJC2xIi8B8A)

### How?

Input as complex numbers.

`(a-b).abs` is the distance between a and b on the complex plane. We have to move b into the 8 adjacent spaces, and calculate distance between the original a and the new b, then take the minimum.

Iterating from -4 to +4 we get the offset table using `c%3-1` for the real part, and `c/3` for the imaginary part:

```ruby
+-----+-----+-----+
| -4  | -3  | -2  |
|-1-i | -i  | 1-i |
+-----+-----+-----+
| -1  |  0  |  1  |
| -1  |  0  |  1  |
+-----+-----+-----+
|  2  |  3  |  4  |
|-1+i |  i  | 1+i |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Looks really obfuscated. How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 79 bytes:

```
lambda x,y,X,Y,n:(min(abs(x-X),n-abs(x-X))**2+min(abs(y-Y),n-abs(y-Y))**2)**0.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoMwEETv/YoeEzspSdQ2KfQ/FHqJFKlQ02A9mK9PEyGgZXdgeLM7zs@vjy2Vm0J/f4S3GbunOS7waNDC3sg4WGK6L1lYQ2FZtrQo5ClnnrU5SzZlUfxcBzcNdiY9EeAQcSSlh8wkSiRVG8bjnYyzZ3r9FXwDNRJWeyhiXYX6gquC1n@1Wq0bcfgB)

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##XcxBCoMwEAXQfU/RZWJ/ionaJgUX3kKhG6VIhZoG68KcPk0MBS0zA5/HzBg7P986k2ZyfXl3r3bsHu1xgUWNBhpV2XafGxkHTSqysJpCsxhokohTdMua6CEE93MunJkGPZOecKTgvgSlh58JZAiTbyz1e8LX3tR6y9MNKgSWe@T@XY7igquEUn9vlVzbs/sC)

Comment: @TheThonnu `A(min(A(x-X),n-A(x-X))+min(A(y-Y),n-A(y-Y))*1j)` is only 70 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `ḋ`, <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ε:?$-Þ∵∆/
```

Thanks @TheThonnu!

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLOtTo/JC3DnuKIteKIhi8iLCIiLCJbMTIsMzRdXG5bNTYsNzhdXG45OSJd)

Input: `[x1, y1] \n [x2, y2] \n N`

Comment: There is a strong conjecture that any Vyxal code can be golfed into `3.1415926` bytes, so please edit it!

Comment: [9 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLOtTo/JC3DnuKIteKIhi8iLCIiLCJbMTIsMzRdXG5bNTYsNzhdXG45OSJd) (or [7.875 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyLhuIs9IiwiIiwizrU6PyQtw57iiLXiiIYvIiwiIiwiWzEyLDM0XVxuWzU2LDc4XVxuOTkiXQ==) in Vyncode)

Comment: [8 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyLhuIsiLCIiLCLGks61fi3DnuKIteKIhi8iLCIiLCJbWzEyLDM0XSxbNTYsNzhdXVxuOTkiXQ==) (jelly port)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
-AD⁶_Ọ²Sƭ
```

##### Explanation

```python
-AD⁶_Ọ²Sƭ  # Implicit input
-A         # Absolute difference between first two inputs
  D        # Duplicate the pair
   ⁶_      # Subtract from the third input
     Ọ     # Elementwise dyadic minimum
      ²    # Square each
       S   # Sum the list
        ƭ  # Square root the sum
           # Implicit output
```

##### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｉ₂ΣＥθ⌊Ｘ⁻↔⁻ι§ηκ⟦⁰ζ⟧²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcnLCsIwEIXhV5nlBEbQei2uiisXhaLLkEWsgYamic1FxZePAT2r7@f0g/S9kybnzmsb8SRDxOucpFcX5wrThK184EzQaqunkp17KY@lUsDmFpxJUf1TEzTxbO/qjQPByBgj4EuCjyio2G/HnDlfVQTrjSj3dkewPxTVtciLp/kC) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as two pairs of coordinates and a number. Explanation:

```
    θ               First input
   Ｅ                Map over coordinates
          ι         Corrent coordinate
         ⁻          Subtract
            η       Second input
           §        Indexed by
             κ      Current index
        ↔           Absolute value
       ⁻            Vectorised subtract
              ⟦  ⟧  List of
               ⁰    Literal integer `0` and
                ζ   Third input
      Ｘ             Vectorised raise to power
                  ² Literal integer `2`
     ⌊              Take the minimum
  Σ                 Take the sum
 ₂                  Take the square root
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>137</del> 96 bytes

Saved 41 bytes thanks to the comment of @corvus_192

---

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5RS8MwEMff8ynuMcGrtHXqUqgg@OKDTyJsiEg62y2jTWsadWX0s9drtCDbDHfHcb//3T/tSpVqqLNtvnLwoLSBPftUJRQJvzcOD1KkN3f1R1bm6X7QVVNbB5Vym/NXxnfY4QKXaEjTvlvHm/qLV9pwlbV8FywEmmBqBcbi7C/vguXEx3bkYugZwFtekMOosus2gVtrVff86Kw26xeRwJPRDlL6MtBraOpKwwseIYQIkQ@6dEBjhAua@zo7oqHfjX2cpHK6HIVHWPplqvOTOBpNZwiXVwjXJJHyH3s5/80fQc96NnwD)

```scala
import math._
(x,y,X,Y,n)=>sqrt(pow(min(abs(x-X),n-abs(x-X)),2)+pow(min(abs(y-Y),n-abs(y-Y)),2))
```

Comment: 96 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5RS8MwEMff8ynuMcGrtHXqUqgg@OKDTyJsiEg62y2jTWsadWX0s9drtCDbDHfHcb//3T/tSpVqqLNtvnLwoLSBPftUJRQJvzcOD1KkN3f1R1bm6X7QVVNbB5Vym/NXxnfY4QKXaEjTvlvHm/qLV9pwlbV8FywEmmBqBcbi7C/vguXEx3bkYugZwFtekMOosus2gVtrVff86Kw26xeRwJPRDlL6MtBraOpKwwseIYQIkQ@6dEBjhAua@zo7oqHfjX2cpHK6HIVHWPplqvOTOBpNZwiXVwjXJJHyH3s5/80fQc96NnwD "Scala – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## SAS 4GL, 71 bytes (or 57)

1. *The answer (in short, just "the point"):*

```
data;set;a=abs(x-p);b=abs(y-q);d=sqrt((a><(N-a))**2+(b><(N-b))**2);run;
```

---

2. *The answer and all details [with details ;-)]:*

Input:

```
data input;
/* x1 y1 x2 y2 N Result */
input x y p q n r;
cards;
1   0   1   1   2   1.00
2   3   2   3   4   0.00
0   0   2   2   4   2.83
0   9   1   1   10  2.24
9   0   9   8   10  2.00
12  34  56  78  99  62.23
0   0   98  98  99  1.41
;
run;
/* to print input data */
proc print data=input;
run;
```

Immediately after "input code" run:
Code:

```
data;set;a=abs(x-p);b=abs(y-q);d=sqrt((a><(N-a))**2+(b><(N-b))**2);run;
```

The:

```
data;set;...run;
```

part is mandatory for every SAS 4GL code so if we select only the "calculation" part:

```
a=abs(x-p);b=abs(y-q);d=sqrt((a><(N-a))**2+(b><(N-b))**2);
```

it is 57 bytes ;-)

Code formatted:

```
data;
  set;
  a = abs(x - p);
  b = abs(y - q);

  d = sqrt(                   
            (a >< (N - a))**2 
          + (b >< (N - b))**2 
          );
run;
```

Comments:

- `i><j` is minimum of i and j, `i**j` is i to power j
- `sqrt(expression)` is the same number of bytes as `(expression)**.5`,
- brackets arounf `N-b` are necessary because `><` takes precedence over substraction,
- result dataset is named `DataX` where X is the first integer not yet used for naming default dataset.

Log:

```
1    data;set;a=abs(x-p);b=abs(y-q);d=sqrt((a><(N-a))**2+(b><(N-b))**2);run;

NOTE: There were 7 observations read from the data set WORK.INPUT.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DATA4 has 7 observations and 9 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

---

Comment: This might be easier to parse/score if you put the scored part of the code at the top and put the rest under a separate heading. Nice answer

Comment: I do not know SAS, but it feels like this needs to accept the input (either as a function or as a full program). Maybe making it a `macro` would do that? At present it looks like a [snippet](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1146/53748). Perhaps there will be no other SAS answers, but requiring answers to take input levels the playing field for if/when another SAS answer comes along.

Comment: In SAS 4GL a dataset is the standard "data carrier" for data steps. It is like R or Python dataframe. The `set` statement takes it as an argument (in this case `set;` [only set and semicolon] means "take the last dataset created"). The same as in R you would write a function but without writing a vector of values, in SAS you would write a data step taking dataset as input but without the process of creating the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 13 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
íaV ËmDaWÃx²¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7WFWIMttRGFXw3iyrA&input=WzEyIDM0XQpbNTYgNzhdCjk5)

```
íaV ËmDaWÃx²¬     :Implicit input of arrays U=[x1,y1] & V=[x2,y2] and integer W=N
í V               :Interleave U & V
 a                :  Reducing each pair by absolute difference
    Ë             :Map each D
     m            :  Minimum with
      DaW         :    Absolute difference of D & W
         Ã        :End map
          x       :Reduce by addition after
           ²      :  Squaring each
            ¬     :Square root
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 57 bytes

```
$=>[x:abs&-&y:abs&-&n:&sqrt+^min@[x,n-x]2(min@[y,n-y])^2]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?N0wy1v)

Takes input as `x1 x2 y1 y2 N`.

```
$=>[                 ; a function
    x:abs&-&         ; assign absolute value of first arg minus second arg to x
    y:abs&-&         ; assign absolute value of third arg minus fourth arg to y
    n:&              ; assign fifth arg to n
    (min@[y,n-y])^2  ; minimum of y and n-y squared
    ^min@[x,n-x]2    ; minimum of x and n-x squared
    +                ; add
    sqrt             ; square root
]                    ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 17 bytes

```
{√+´×˜⌊´|-⊸⋈-´}
```

[Try it at BQN REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=VG9yb2lkYWxfZGlzdCDihpAge+KImivCtMOXy5zijIrCtPCdlah8LeKKuOKLiC3CtPCdlal9CgoxMCBUb3JvaWRhbF9kaXN0IOKfqOKfqDAsOeKfqSzin6gxLDHin6nin6k=)

```
{√+´×˜⌊´|-⊸⋈-´}  # function taking N as left arg ()
                    # and [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]] as right arg ():
              -´   # vectorized fold-subtract: [x1-x2,y1-y2]
          -⊸⋈      # joined to negative of itself: [[x1-x2,y1-y2],[x2-x1],[y2-y1]]
        |          # all modulo N
      ⌊´            # vectorized fold-minimum
    ×˜              # vectorized multiply each element by itself
  +´                # sum (fold-addition)
 √                  # square-root
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 104 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZJNT4QwEIbv@yvmYtLGLsuXK2DYxMSLB7kYT5uNKR@uGD5LV6OE345TJIT1gvbQ9J32fabtTBPxjPdl@JZEEh54WkC7WgHEyQvkqAgXx8aDWyH45/5RirQ4HqgHT0UqwcejgKPCqMwKIktRpjHPnuO0kWSwEIOBThlMwkBhUqpsmw0Yi36TgTX5R2FPfn3Rr8/zmyr33G9qjvUXhPv7CYY@MAaEaS8i3PktUDjniOVfVC@3J8LVlsG1YrguMpCwxVtY//sL10H7nGFotipHh9VXxT8DePCD2N8X8jASxjXO1N/dlacwS7AjesJZyAIMte88g9jn2ldakZBqOa/aiDcJqViN26Ra15cBvQi6m5zLV62phSSxOkWEvxtCVflBhkWOfShYsBaUYe9ozSmnXd/13w)

```scala
(a,b,N)=>{val d=a.zip(b).map{case(p,q)=>(p-q+N)%N};math.sqrt(d.map(r=>math.pow(math.min(r,N-r),2)).sum)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLNToQwFIX38xRnY9JGZIDBEUjGxMSNC9kYV2ZiyhTHGv6EjkYn8@x4iw4BN2hX9zQ9X@9tT7MRmWjbMnlJNxq3QhXYz2aATJ@Qk2Ki3jYRrupafDzc6VoV2zWPcF8ojRUdBa2KdnVWMF3WpZIie5Sq0ayzMNeCwy30wiXhcW5s8zncSb9nYdH7f4Tf@51JvzO83zN3D/2eHSz@ggh/j@A6HaNDeP4kIhx2QSIYI6Zf0Uzu94TzpYULwwhDYhBhSV0s/vcWYUD2IcO1ffMdh@PvjwnimIGbQq8tJGMZR6CCcnFd7pIs7ZPxJjJIUsL@VBVLuJ2LCntsRJOCCUUcxbG6NDXOSOAUMccJYmrD@HOhn@3mtdZMGiuTypzudqvynXVFTiGVhIqJINV3vOxml/NumMOsbb8A)

```scala
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(1, 0), Array(1, 1), 2))    // 1
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(2, 3), Array(2, 3), 4))    // 0
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(0, 0), Array(2, 2), 4))    // 2.83
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(0, 9), Array(1, 1), 10))   // 2.24
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(9, 0), Array(9, 8), 10))   // 2
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(12, 34), Array(56, 78), 99)) // 62.23
    println(toroidal_dist(Array(0, 0), Array(98, 98), 99)) // 1.41
  }

  def toroidal_dist(a: Array[Int], b: Array[Int], N: Int): Double = {
    val d = a.zip(b).map { case (ai, bi) => (ai - bi + N) % N }
    math.sqrt(d.map(di => math.pow(math.min(di, N - di), 2)).sum)
  }
}
```