# Euclidean distance on projective plane

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

Motivated by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/260743/calculate-euclidean-distance-on-a-torus)

#### Background

Let we have a square sheet of flexible material.
Roughly speaking, we may [close it on itself four ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon#Examples_of_Fundamental_Polygons_Generated_by_Parallelograms):

[image]

Here the color marks the edges that connect and the vectors indicate the direction.
The sphere and torus are obtained without flipping the sides, Klein bottle — with one flipping edge,
and projective plane with both.

Surprisingly torus, not a sphere, in many senses is the simplest construct.
For example, you [can't comb a hairy ball flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) without creating a cowlick (but torus can).
This is why torus is often used in games, puzzles and research.

#### Specific info

This is a separate picture for fundamental polygon (or closing rule) of projective plane (for `1..N` notation):
[image]

Neighborhood of `[1, 1]` cell for `N x N` lattice:
[image]

Example how to find distance for points `(2, 4)` and `(5, 3)` in `5 x 5` projective plane:
[image]
Green paths are shortest, so it is the distance.

#### Task

For given two points and size of lattice,
find euclidean distance between points on the projective plane.

#### I/O

Flexible, in any suitable formats

#### Test cases

For `1..N` notation
`N, p1, p2 → distance`
For a better understanding, also indicated distance on torus (for same points and size):

```
5, [1, 1], [1, 1] → 0.0 (0.0)
5, [2, 4], [5, 3] → 2.24 (2.24)
5, [2, 4], [4, 1] → 2.0   (1.41)
10, [2, 2], [8, 8] → 4.12 (5.66)
10, [1, 1], [10, 10]  → 1.0 (1.41)
10, [4, 4], [6, 6]  → 2.83 (2.83)
```

Comment: In your diagram, I think the (2, 4) and (5, 3) on the right are in the wrong place - the (5, 3) should be on the same row as the one on the left and the (2, 4) doesn't fit on the diagram because it's not wide enough.

Comment: @Neil  Yes, it looks like that, I’ll check and fix

Answer (score 4):

## [julia](https://julialang.org/), <s>104</s> 97 bytes

This solution uses the quotient space metric.
For the projective plane, if \$\sim\$ is the equivalence relation induced by the edge identification (i.e. \$(p, 0) \sim (N-p, N); (0, p) \sim (N, N-p)\$) and \$d\$ is the Euclidean metric, then the projective plane metric is
$$
d'(a, b)
= \min_{w \sim w'} [d(a, w) + d(b, w')].
$$

To implement this, we create two grids \$x\$ and \$y\$ spanning \$[0, N]^2\$ such that \$x_{ij} \sim y_{ij}\$ and compute \$d(a, x_{ij}) + d(b, y_{ij})\$ for each corresponding pair of grid entries.

We make the vertical spacing between grid points \$0.005\$ to make sure that the result is correct to two decimal places.

```
u&v=((h=u-v.-.5)'h)^.5
g(N,a,b)=minimum(w->a&w+b&((N.-2w)any(w.%N.==0)+w),vcat.((r=0:.005:N)',r))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZBRCoJAEIbfPcW-pDM4u6ymIsJ2BC8QBVuQGiohrkvQTXrppZt0iW5TYQWB9DQz_N_w_zPn697Ulb5crqbf8fSujTsogFIZPgguYvRKXIvYKSAnTRtUTdVWjWnA8oV2rb9xAXLBQ4u6PYIVs1woJdG3SMNW9wKgUzITUsZZjh51iG-jWwExsWVALFh9KrLTgh26qu3r1hn1kFj00p_9_J8eTewHcgTCF5ASSyeBb4LnEMhJJHqbJMSSH2C85fO8Bw)

Thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush) for a 7-byte improvement!

#### How?

```
# u&v is the distance between u-0.5 (centre of cell u) and v.
u&v = ((h = u - v .- .5)'h)^.5

# Minimise the function w -> d(a, w) + d(b, w')
g(N, a, b) = minimum(

    # (N .- 2w)any(w .% N .== 0) + w is N-w on the edges of x and w otherwise.
    w -> a&w + b&((N .- 2w)any(w .% N .== 0) + w),
    
    # Map over a grid of pairs [x1, x2] spanning [0, N]^2.
    vcat.((r = 0:.005:N)', r)
)
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Looks like it's suitable for more complicated topologies

Comment: [97 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZBRCoJAEIbfPcW-pDM4u6ymIsJ2BC8QBVuQGiohrkvQTXrppZt0iW5TYQWB9DQz_N_w_zPn697Ulb5crqbf8fSujTsogFIZPgguYvRKXIvYKSAnTRtUTdVWjWnA8oV2rb9xAXLBQ4u6PYIVs1woJdG3SMNW9wKgUzITUsZZjh51iG-jWwExsWVALFh9KrLTgh26qu3r1hn1kFj00p_9_J8eTewHcgTCF5ASSyeBb4LnEMhJJHqbJMSSH2C85fO8Bw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
_~jUŒHƲ€N⁹ṭ"_þ/ẎÆḊ€Ṃ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the size on the left and a pair of pairs (the points) on the right and yields the Euclidean distance of the projective plane.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUMAvP9qZWxsef//X35qVcWSSMay4oKsTuKBueG5rSJfw74v4bqOw4bhuIrigqzhuYL///8xMP9bWzIsIDJdLCBbOCwgOF1d)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##fY8tEsIwEIU9p8igk2mSpn83QOFQnU4VptMLYJgBgUAguAQGDIoiMB24R3qRsN2kpcBA1M63L@@9LeZluTAmXxaz@37yODfr47RZVbo6jfP65unrrt7oyxawrtamPngwmRReQAlTGSUpU5QEWTt9MYQpzEwg9SmRFgpgsp04Jf4/oewtxcAyARojjSlJLPQ7SyYHngICWIIYPgnex3OXLjplBMIQhSEl0Y@DMoMQHbCqcA4jYjlk44fAdfjk6qVvq@ECW8Mh8duiT@C292ClnBkUDXGRPQE).

#### How?

```
_~jUŒHƲ€N⁹ṭ"_þ/ẎÆḊ€Ṃ - Link: Size = S; Points = [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
_                    - {Size} subtract {Points} -> [[S-x1, S-y1], [S-x2, S-y2]]
       €             - for each of these pairs, [a, b]:
      Ʋ              -   last four links as a monad:
 ~                   -     bitwise NOT (vectorises) -> [-1-a, -1-b]
   U                 -     upend -> [b,a]
  j                  -     join  -> [-1-a, b, a, -1-b]
    ŒH               -     halve -> [[-1-a, b], [a, -1-b]]
        N            - negate    -> [[a+1, -b], [-a, b+1]]
         ⁹           - chain's right argument -> [[x1, y1], [x2, y2]]
           "         - zip with:
          ṭ          -   tack -> [[[S-x1+1, y1-S], [x1-S, S-y1+1], [x1, y1]],
                                  [[S-x2+1, y2-S], [x2-S, S-y2+1], [x2, y2]],
                                 ]
              /      - reduce by:
             þ       -   table with:
            _        -     subtraction
               Ẏ     - tighten
                ÆḊ€  - vector norm of each
                   Ṃ - minimum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 83 bytes (-35 thanks to @xnor)

```python
lambda N,A,B:min(map(abs,(B-A,C:=B-1j*N-~N-2*B.real-A,D:=1+1j-C-2*A,C+2j*N,D+2*N)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY-xboMwEIZ3nuK22OSwsEMQQmIIyczSMc1AGlCIDLYcUrVLxz5A1yyRqvZ5umbtk9QEkrbL-e6_T__9Pn7q53armtN7mdx_HNrSi853Mq_XmxwynGEa11VD6lyTfL1HknoznMdJ6vGdm3kvmSfclJkil1ZfxAkf8503t6KlxsIiuBgLN6OUDtbHqtbKtFDn7dZxSmVAQtWA0kVDfBo7UKGCBCTba1m1ZPT9-jaiTp_E6sVjLkllBXUd1EDSpb-yujZV05ILjgpNnBh1aDaktNKDqrUsnog7o799SikKiipJzBDxdP6aIiw5Al9dX7AxwGc-EFuo0-0FQtDtbT_p94KJAEhX_xPBzUFYBwDCWcCpw_2eER0TIUQ9EzAugExZGA7ILYgduL-CC8W7LH98guFWiBAOiGDRpIsTTYaP_QA)

#### Obsolete [Python](https://www.python.org), 118 bytes

```python
lambda N,A,B,o=.5+.5j:min(map(lambda x:abs(A-o-x),[B:=B-o,C:=N/o+B-2*B.real,-B,2*N-B,2j*N-B,4*N*o-B,-C,C+2j*N,2*N-C]))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBBboMwEEX3nGJ2tcngYgcQQmIR2HOBlAVpQCECjAiJ0gv0AN1mE6lqz9Nttj1J7eCk7WbG_v9p5tunz_5l3Mju_F7FTx_7sXLCy6Ep2tW6gAwXmKCMmT9j_jZq6460RU-Me4yK1Y4sHOkcKS6TKE4ciWkUZ49yljjCTthQFg06CQo703V7bZ6d2VJ1J8V0prWrneaUmu2nuu3lMEJbjBvLquQADdQdyL7siEsjC2qUEEPDdn1Tj-Th-_XtgVpTWKWXh6IhtRLk7SINSZdurvR-qLuRmLfhEMWD3HdrUinpWbZ9Ux6JvaC_54RSFFR9QzyYiOfLl4-w5Ag8v3VQMcBlLhBVqKV9geBpX53nky-Y8IDo-p_w7hOEmgBAOPM4tbg7MUIzIUI4MR7jAojPgsAg9yDqwt0crhTXWf7M8cyuACEwiGDhXMcJ5-ZhPw)

Expects input coordinates as complex numbers.

Comment: It looks like your code checks 9 options, which I'll venture are a 3x3 box around the original square? If so, I think you don't have to check the diagonally-adjacent ones because the original copy of the point is always closer.

Comment: Thanks, @xnor. I'm having a hard time getting intuition for this parameterization.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 94 bytes

```python
lambda n,X,Y,x,y:min(abs(X-a+(Y-b)*1j)for k in[-n,n]for a,b in[(x,y),(n+1-x,y+k),(x+k,n+1-y)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5NDoJADIX3nKLLVkrCKBpCwj0gymKIEkegEMQfTo8ziiau@t7Xvrb9NJ472cT9MFfpYW50Wx41CGec85OnpDWCurxiFmgf86CklbpQ1Q1Qg5F9ICyFc5pL59FGiFF8FVjl11Y//Zqdn6ig@XE2zQlU4tkLaE@4vk2kp7tu0Eh/G5HIg34wMmKFvzeI5i3DXjGo4ls9R9YMkSNWb/5J9J5R4QetHYoZ4gX9NlmjwgVGS3THsCte)

Easier to understand as:

```python
lambda n,X,Y,x,y:min(abs(X-a+(Y-b)*1j)for a,b in[(x,y),(n+1-x,y-n),(n+1-x,y+n),(x-n,n+1-y),(x+n,n+1-y)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BDoIwDIbvPEWPnXQJEyTExPeAIIcRIcxgJYiKT4@bAsZTv3772657Dc2Vw6Trp/pwnFp9KU8amFLKaKTX/mIYdXnDVGofM1mKjTqL@tqDphIM52hDgpB9JS1J/rHveJRMrneZ0V@4ENOzMW0Fau/ZW2iPuXe76VA9dIuGu/uAQnjQ9YYHrHH9kBDTjiBXBKpYqufMliByxnL4b6JPRgVftXUqIUhmtW6yjQpmGc2jMUFcvAE)

Fixes one point in place, and picks the closest version of the other point out of 5 options -- the original and the four reflections across the edges of the square. There's no need to consider diagonally-adjacent copies because they're always further from the fixed point than the original.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3, 458 bytes

```py
R=range
E=enumerate
def T(d,x,y,X,Y):
 if y%2:d=[[(*a,W+Y*len(d),k)for k,(*a,_,_)in E(i[::-1])]for W,i in E(d)]
 if x%2:d=[[(*a,W,k+X*len(i))for k,(*a,_,_)in E(i)]for W,i in E(d[::-1])]
 return[j for k in d for j in k]
def f(n,p,P):
 d=[[(i,j,i-1,j-1)for j in R(1,n+1)]for i in R(1,n+1)];O=[*T(d,0,0,0,0),*T(d,0,1,0,-1),*T(d,1,0,1,0),*T(d,0,1,0,1),*T(d,1,0,-1,0)]
 return min(((X-x)**2+(Y-y)**2)**0.5 for a,b,x,y in O for A,B,X,Y in O if[a,b]==p and[A,B]==P)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZFda4MwFIbv/RXnZpDocRj7QXF4sUGvW8qgLUGKQ92iayrBQv31Lh9b14@NEHLO@yTvyUnavvs4yNGsVcOwSlUu30tvnpbyuC9V3pVeUVbwSgo8YY8b3NLEA1FB/xAnRco58XNcB1v/s5SkoNjQ6qCgQSPvcEeFhDkRPElCltHMsDUKsGpBM@t0unTCJthYL0H/dLr1@HH2QJXdUUlegz1mcGHD2oRNZtuoiMQWl6YFW1FgjSJkWIeMnveuCEMZMFdJXClPi5T75i0iNyh@Z0xP7eFS5oQreMlCA883hr2QhJBNeKK@HwdkG/Ym0DN6nNgOcnwzj29usrDCM76Yn3CCqLjekKVpC7ksuGY6XtKhVUJ2pCIT5AyBZQhupdT7RcBjhLFhOh79x8Y351jkYGzgDGF2B88VdcKiOzz@Np4iTDUcvgA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 104 bytes

*Saved 9 bytes by refactoring in a way similar to [what xnor did](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/261202/58563)*

Expects `(N,x1,y1,x2,y2)`.

```javascript
(N,x,y,X,Y)=>Math.min(...(g=q=>[x,x+q,N-x].map((v,i)=>Math.hypot(X-v,Y-[y,N-y,y+q][i])))(N++),...g(1-N))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7BboMwDAbge58iR1s4hqTp1At9g3FuhTigrgWmlsBAiDw9S4mqHdpJ/iUfPv32dzmVw/mn6UbZ2q/Lck0XyGgmR0c6YXr4LMea700LzAxV2qeHfKY56imTc8H3sgOYqHnC2nV2hKOc6CRz540jF/VF3hSICFkUIfmeCpTMEJezbQd7u/DNVnAFsSOh1glBFHEsEk42r06TMN74TWyD06zN/9D8FeqXQpWszo/YPxKcYaXfwPDhuiUBqreFJhz@eOR5eL9dfgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 41 bytes

```
⊞υηＦ⟦θ±θ⟧Ｆ²⊞υＥη⎇⁼κμ⁻⊕θλ⁺λιＩ₂⌊ＥυΣＸＥι⁻λ§ζμ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY29rsIwDIV3nsKjI5mBqkydrhADA6gCtqpDVHxvI9KEpgl/Lx8MV1iybJ1jf6frdei8tjnXaeoxEfSqmv36ANiMBDv@05FxVK2Cj1go@B5u9QV7giMHp8MD12PSdsIzwaDENC5NuHFd4IFd5JMwCKx0bcWwBEZJVbM6GBdxpaeIByEE3nsfUd7NkAZ8Z0jUQdba3zh8BPPFC@UnbtyJ7/h8xyrBF@q/qpybJUFTEJStzJJg0bZ5frUv) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the size and the two points as input. Explanation:

```
⊞υη
```

Push the first point to the predefined empty list.

```
Ｆ⟦θ±θ⟧Ｆ²
```

Loop over each orthogonal direction.

```
⊞υＥη⎇⁼κμ⁻⊕θλ⁺λι
```

Push the transform of the point in that direction to the list.

```
Ｉ₂⌊ＥυΣＸＥι⁻λ§ζμ²
```

Output the minimum Euclidean distance from the second point to any of the five points inthe list.

I tried writing it as a single expression but it still came out to 41 bytes:

```
Ｉ₂⌊Ｅ⊞ＯＥ⁴Ｅη⎇﹪⁺ιμ²⁻⊕θλ⎇÷ι²⁺λθ⁻λθηΣＸＥι⁻λ§ζμ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoMwEIRfJccV0kPFnnoq7cWDVGpv4iHoQgIx0ZjYn5dPkwhtB5Zhh53l6zkzvWbS@9oIZeHMFgvN7JjBm9YWKqHE6Eao2AS1W/h1QsOsNikoKInGKbmjUcy8oNKDkxpq6RYQlIwZJXmY8CUEpeoNjqgsDjCHVGa/YqnsRaxiwFiLlfRCUjJ/62mJooSHaQJVrR@4oYi/q5Mt1YBPeEeALCFsOnrfHihpc0qKLnjg33ed363yAw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 168 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7BboMwEETvfMUe7WATILSKqKjUYw/lElUiqnowFFIjIASsCor4drqGNhdSazRer57G0yaiEJMs63OjoNUPqxTq0xraS6MYlLIaDeMc52mi4EXICobpI80gI6H/XCnWzd7PHs1@1E6D4UsURLCYBqTjETuaPQ@5Qx/IIb3gXvCQRWand6tbmCH9ljVosudHFjN05EM@T2aIqRRb1kMi2pRIltPgUdclciPNfJPT0dK9JwBdtcTWRDSn1oenphH920E1sjq9Ux9eK6kggMEAPDVuVVGRjNwxcK6iFLZbsC17DbkMPAY47BbItVzvP8q7RrmrKMeeKdQetVCe5bg3sN9SerIX0LkZt/x4j/r7dL9DbDTG6Qc)

```scala
def f(N:Int,x:Int,y:Int,X:Int,Y:Int)={val(a,b)=(x-X,Y+y-N-1);(Seq(a,a-N,X+x-N-1,X+x-N-1,X+x-N-1,a+N)zip Seq(y-Y,b,y-Y-N,N-b,y-Y+N,b)).map{case(i,j)=>sqrt(i*i+j*j)}.min}
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDBasJAEL3nK95xV9OYxLSIYKHQSw/NpRSU4mETo11JYprdFlPx29NJNqaIlsIsszPvzZvdp2KRirqWWbErNVRTOZnQ785BfZTaRibzo2Xtom0SazwLmeNgAatkjTULp3jKibPvctXleZcXbeZTPO4@ozTBrJ0FvkQKQdVDWYqK7XGDOYk0iU5I8xi2ZUjH@680c0OEvNeOeu2KwAU9hPDqd6TtmlVNh53B/IQPG/wc6jespNIijxNFm5jAtywQcfKtOCAWKgGTNrYcs3s0LjI5kKSzHVDr2Gr08w75Sx2y2JiakcNMlBs1NT94e9GlzDdLMvE1l7q3sKCuTnO2Zrd286UuOMdoBNdxL0m@jcAGXcaG5Dt@8Bcr6KX8CynPbVkUEwrDChzPv0LrHtXcXEP0rsqZjXcUp6WTcWvK0arrHw)

```scala
import scala.math.{sqrt, min}

object Main {
  def f(N: Int, x: Int, y: Int, X: Int, Y: Int): Double = {
    val a = Array(x - X, x - X - N, X + x - N - 1, X + x - N - 1, X + x - N - 1, x - X + N)
    val b = Array(y - Y, Y + y - N - 1, y - Y - N, N - (Y + y - N - 1), y - Y + N, Y + y - N - 1)
    val distances = (a zip b).map{ case (i, j) => sqrt(i*i + j*j) }
    distances.min
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(5, 1, 1, 1, 1)) // 0.0
    println(f(5, 2, 4, 5, 3)) // 2.24
    println(f(5, 2, 4, 4, 1)) // 2.0
    println(f(10, 2, 2, 8, 8)) // 4.12
    println(f(10, 1, 1, 10, 10)) // 1.0
    println(f(10, 4, 4, 6, 6)) // 2.83
  }
}
```